Please explain DSL opensearch error - '[size] query malformed, no start_object after query name')
{
  "size": 5,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "knn": {
            "page_content_embedding": {
              "vector": [
                -0.03517193719744682,
                0.0035374287981539965,
                0.012508848682045937,
                -0.011280038394033909,
                -0.028579039499163628,
                0.031669460237026215,
                -0.018866287544369698,
                -0.02781379222869873,
                -0.045738235116004944,
                "......"
              ],
              "k": 5
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "match_phrase": {
          "credit_cards": "Product One"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Why does this say
opensearchpy.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', '[size] query malformed, no start_object after query name')
Opensearch dashboard says there are 245 hits for
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "credit_cards": "Product One"
    }
  }
}

